# read votes from text file and tally the votes

Tags: python

I need to read all of the votes from a text document with a list of names, and then have each name printed with their corresponding occurrences.

Code:

```
from collections import Counter

file = open("votes.txt").readlines()

count = dict(Counter(file))

for name in count:
  name_ = name.rstrip()
  print(name_, ': ', count[name])
```

The text document:

```
Pedro Sanchez
Trisha Jenner
Trisha Jenner
Summer Wheatley
Pedro Sanchez
Pedro Sanchez
Trisha Jenner
Pedro Sanchez
Summer Wheatley
```

output received:

```
Pedro Sanchez :  4
Trisha Jenner :  3
Summer Wheatley :  2
```

expected output:

```
Pedro Sanchez: 4
Trisha Jenner: 3
Summer Wheatley: 2
```

How would it be possible to strip that space after the end of the name?

Comment: what is the difficulty that you face?

Comment: counting the ammount the name is shown and than outputting the amount in that format.

Comment: i mean what attempt did you make to solve that problem and what is the difficulty that you face in doing that?

Comment: i have attempted to sort all of them into a list and a dictionary, then print each name from the dictionary than the number it occurs in the list. eg: ('Pedro Sanchez'), however i cannot figure out how

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a coding service... The idea is not to post a problem and get the solution. This is a community to help fellow programmers, so post any attempt you made in solving the problem and we will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your printing issue: use `print(f'{name_}: {count[name]}')` instead of `print(name_, ': ', count[name])`

Here is also another approach using no additional Python modules.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

votes = [
    "Pedro Sanchez",
    "Trisha Jenner",
    "Trisha Jenner",
    "Summer Wheatley",
    "Pedro Sanchez",
    "Pedro Sanchez",
    "Trisha Jenner",
    "Pedro Sanchez",
    "Summer Wheatley"
]

occurence = {}
for person in votes:
    # remove trailing whitespaces
    person = person.rstrip()
    occurence.setdefault(person, 0)
    occurence[person] = occurence[person] + 1

for person, count in occurence.items():
    print(f'{person}: {count}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collections module here

```
from collections import Counter

file = open("file.txt").readlines()

count = dict(Counter(file))
```

output

```
{'Pedro Sanchez\n': 4, 'Trisha Jenner\n': 3, 'Summer Wheatley\n': 2}
```

Comment: how would I separate out each name and number from the dictionary and display all on new lines? as shown in the question

Comment: @MarkIngram it seems like you're asking the wrong question here in this whole post. Its seems your problem is about printing and not reading the file. To print simply iterate the dict: `for k,v in count.items(): print(k, ':', v)`

Answer (score 0):

Since Sahil has suggested a solution with the `collections` module, I would like to suggest the `pandas` approach to solve this. Assuming you have a text file in the same format, read the text file and do a simple `value_counts()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('names.txt', header = None)
print(df[0].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
Pedro Sanchez      4
Trisha Jenner      3
Summer Wheatley    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: how would i have that print like i have in the question??